# @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") returns nullpointer exception instead accessdeniedexpection [method level security]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm currently stuck on these problem. when I tried using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`  it works, but not on `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")`.  I'm trying to make it return a `accessdeniedexception` but it returns `nullpointerexception`.

does anyone have encountered these kind of issue before?

Comment: Please post the (complete) stacktrace of this nullpointer exception. And I think that in order to find the problem, one will need the Spring security configuration too.

Comment: [12/6/13 18:28:56:940 CST] 000000e6 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet eloans in application eloans_war. Exception created : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)

Comment: spring security is already configured. anotation @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')") is working when I use it in method level, but @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") is not working instead it throws nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

I never thought that there is a custom class that extends the SecurityRoot.class but forgot that TrustResolver.class is not pass causing the nullpointer exception. I have just set the trustResolver and it work as I wanted.